# JS; Can someone correct my Quick Sort function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, quicksort

I still have difficulties using recursive calls.
My function exceeds the max call stack. Any help please?

```
function quickSort(arr) {
    let n = arr[arr.length-1];
    const inf = [];
    const sup = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]<= n){inf.push(arr[i])}
        else(sup.push(arr[i]));
    }
    if(inf.length === 1 && sup.length === 1){
        return inf.concat(sup)
    }else if(inf.length === 1 && sup.length > 1){
        quickSort(sup);
        return inf.concat(sup)
    }else if(inf.length > 1 && sup.length === 1){
        quickSort(inf);
        return inf.concat(sup)
    }else{
        quickSort(inf);
        quickSort(sup);
        return inf.concat(sup)
    }
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What *should* this do if either `inf` or `sup` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example array `arr = [3,2,7,5,4,6]`.
In the first recursive call

```
inf = [3,2,7,5,4,6]
sup = [7]
```

Now, since `sup.length === 1` and `inf.length > 1`, the execution would go into the third if-else condition. In this recursive call, we have

```
inf = [3,2,5,4,6] // Same as the original array sent into parameter
sup = []
```

This basically falls in an infinite recursive call loop.

In order to recover from infinite loops like this, you need to add a condition to check when `inf.length === 0` or `sup.length === 0`.

**Possible solution:** In the for loop, during the last iteration, you can check if either of the arrays are empty, and since the last iteration would always result in the equal case, i.e in the above code `arr[i] = n`, you can push it to the empty array and move ahead with the further if else conditions.

Considering the test case I took earlier, in the second iterative call, I would push `6` not to `inf[]` but to `sup[]` making the `inf[]` and `sup[]` arrays as follows:

```
inf = [3,2,5,4]
sup = [6]
```

This will resolve the infinite loop issue.